# using/typedef of namespace in header

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, typedef, using

I have a use case for the `std::placeholder` in a test application but am wondering if, in an effort to make things look a little cleaner on an API side, there is a way to bend `using`, `typedef` or even `#define` to alias the namespace at the header level.

```
// .../datarequestprocessor.h
class DataRequestProcessor {
public:
    using ProcessFunction = std::function<void(const ResultData &)>;
    using RequestResultHandle = std::placeholders; // No go. Same with ::_1
    ...
};

// ../datarequestprocessor.cpp
ProcessFunction DataRequestProcessor::prepOne()
{
    auto func = std::bind( &DataModel::setData,
                           m_model,
                           RequestResultHandle::_1 );
    return func;
}
... // For other variations.
```

This is purely semantic and also just an effort to learn about the nature of the `using` keyword. More of a learning experience then a real world application proposition.

Cheers

Comment: You can do a namespace alias (`std::placeholder` is a namespace, not a type), but it has to be at namespace or function scope: `namespace RequestResultHandle = std::placeholder`)

Comment: "No go" is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `std::placeholders` (or `std::placeholder`, which doesn't exist), which you'd have found out if you'd played around and discovered that this problem is about how you're using namespace aliases (which cannot be at class scope).

Comment: Ah yes. `std::placeholders` is what I meant to type :) Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it at the *header* level, then it's a simple matter of introducing a namespace alias:

```
namespace RequestResultHandle = std::placeholders;
```

The above won't be accepted inside a class however.

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::placeholder`.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - Gee, begrudge me a mistyped 's' why don't you

Comment: This is actually the best answer now ^_^

Answer (score 2):

> in an effort to make things look a little cleaner on an API side

Ideally, you shouldn't be exposing placeholders in the API at all. If you are doing so, you haven't shown it in your code above.

If you are just using placeholders in the implementation, the following will do the trick:

```
ProcessFunction DataRequestProcessor::prepOne()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto func = std::bind( &DataModel::setData,
                           m_model,
                           _1 );
    return func;
}
```

Comment: Right on. Yeah, API level probably not the best for any of this. It should be angled for more internal work among cohorts. Thanks for the input! I was just hoping the result, being of varying volition based on the model `setData` function, could utilize a 'pretty' word rather than using `std::placeholders` anywhere we need to apply a `bind`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `using` directive to alias a `namespace`.

If you are motivated, you can define your own `namespace` in which you can alias specific types from another namespace.

```
namespace RequestResultHandle
{
    using _1 = std::placeholders::_1;
    using _2 = std::placeholders::_2;

    ...
}
```

Now, you can use `RequestResultHandle::_1` instead of `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: _"You can't use the using directive to alias a namespace."_ No but with a trivial tweak (say `namespace` instead of `union`) [you can do just that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cba14ca09ae0381d), without needing to name each namespace member in turn.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, Did you just say `union` instead of `using`? You are loosing your touch :)

Comment: It's late haha :D